# Proof by contradiction. Statement negation

Tags: real-analysis

This should be an easy question. Yet, the provided solution confuses me.
The question comes from "Understanding analysis" by S. Abbot, 2nd edition ([Exercise 1.2.11](https://books.google.it/books?id=p1t1CQAAQBAJ&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

> Negate the statement. Make an intuitive guess as to whether the claim or its negation is the true statement.
>
> > (b) There exists a real number $x > 0$ such that $x < 1/n\;\;\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The provided solution says:

[image]

---

The solution seems correct, apart from: shouldn't the negation be with $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e.:
$$\forall x >0 \;\; \exists n \in \mathbb{N}: x \geq 1/n$$
?

Comment: The statement given is false, so it cannot be proved, not by contradiction nor by any other method. Your negation of the statement is correct, and is therefore a true statement.

Comment: I suspect that you have made a mistake in transcribing the problem from the book, or else that it is a typo in the book.

Comment: The statement has been correctly transcribed from the book.

Comment: Thank you for the link in your comment below. Indeed you have transcribed the statement correctly, but the question is not "Provide a proof by contradiction for" the statement, it is simply to negate the statement and put your answer in a "positive" form, and then to make an educated guess as to which of the statement and its negation is true.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to contrast that with the solution, which gives a proof by contradiction.

Comment: The solution that you quote is a flawed attempt at a proof of a true statement, that is not the same as the true statement that you correctly give as the negation of the statement given in the question. The flaw in the purported proof is that "for all n" should be "there exists n".

Comment: You are right, thank you for clarifying that.
Question: the statement given in the question implies the statement which is proven. Right?
This means that if the former is true, the latter is true as well. Does it also mean that if the former is false then the latter is not necessarily false?

Comment: You are welcome ! The statement given in the question is false, and therefore it implies ANY statement, whether the latter is true or false (implication is false only when the hypothesis is true and the conclusion false). The negation of the statement given in the question is true, and can be used to prove the other true statement (the one in the solution), as follows: By the hypothesis, there exists m in N such that 1/m <= 1/n. Let x=1/(2m). Then x < 1/n. About your last sentence - in general, the contrapositive of a true implication need not be true. I'm not an expert in logic though !

Comment: @Sandy Ursu: your negation is correct. The author just does a proof by contradiction to show that for all $n$ there exists an $x>0$ such that $x < \frac {1}{n} $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding [**Ex.1.2.11** (b)](https://books.google.it/books?id=p1t1CQAAQBAJ&pg=PA13) :

> Form the logical negation of [...] there exists a real number $x > 0$ such that  $x < \dfrac 1 n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$,

the formula to be negated is :

> $\exists x > 0 \ \forall n \in \mathbb N \ (x < \dfrac 1 n)$.

Thus, tou are right. The correct negation will be :

> > $\forall x > 0 \ \exists n \in \mathbb N \ (x \ge \dfrac 1 n)$.

---

But in the solution provided, the author exhibits a proof of the statement; from this, we have to assume that the formula above is not what the author alludes to.

We have instead to transalte the semi-formal statement with :

> $\forall n \in \mathbb N  \ \exists x > 0 \ (x < \dfrac 1 n)$

which is true.

Its negation will then be : $\exists n \in \mathbb N  \ \forall x > 0 \ (x \ge \dfrac 1 n)$.

Comment: Is this in the 2nd edition of the book? (I've just edited my description to mention that)

Comment: Exercise 1.2.11 [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=p1t1CQAAQBAJ&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 10):

This is why putting quantifiers at the end of a formula is a bad practice. It creates ambiguity. The statements

1. $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})(\exists x > 0)(x < \frac{1}{n})$
2. $(\exists x > 0)(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})(x < \frac{1}{n})$

are not equivalent. The second one is obviously false, however it's more likely to interpret your formulation as the second statement. Undoubtedly, the first statement is what's actually meant. For proving by contradiction, we need its negation which goes as follows:
$$(\exists n \in \mathbb{N})(\forall x > 0)\left(x \ge \frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Comment: The second statement (which is the one from the question) implies the first one (which is the one from the provided solution).

Comment: Only because the second statement is false, and a false statement implies any statement.

Comment: If (2) were true it would still imply (1), no?

Comment: @SanduUrsu Think of the second statement. Can you really find a real number $x>0$  that is larger than every possible $1/n$?

Comment: @AaronStevens I suppose you mean lower. (2) is false, yes. But I meant in general, statements of the form $\exists x \;\forall y \;P(x,y)$ imply $\forall y \;\exists x \; P(x,y)$.

Comment: @SanduUrsu Oh I see. Yes I think you are right.

Answer (score 1):

> > There exists a real number $x > 0$ such that $x < 1/n\;\;\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Is this statement really valid? Let's check.

$nx<1 \;\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ is valid only for $x\leq 0$.

(Because $n$ becomes very large, and if $x\gt 0$ then $nx$ diverges to infinity)

So there is no such $x$ exist.

Comment: @AaronStevens yes absolutely. See the last line of my answer.

Comment: @AaronStevens is $x$ exist? How long  $x$ close to $0$?

Comment: You should note that carefully..... We are working on **For all n in N**

Comment: @AaronStevens Here $n$ is not fixed. We are going to find a positive $x$ which is strictly less than $1/n$ for every $n$.

Comment: ${1,1/2,1/3,1/4,...}$. What is the infimum of this collection?

Comment: I see the issue. Your interpretation of the ambiguous statement is different than the intention. Look at the solution provided.

Comment: Question has been edited. I have post the answer before the edit.

Comment: @AvinashN argues that the statement is false. This is relevant to the question. The negation would be true. If one would attempt to prove the negation by contradiction, again, he could use these arguments.